# Do hallucinogenics affect chronic pain?

Tags: psychopharmacology, pain

As noted in a previous question, hallucinogenics, such as psilocybin, [have been used to treat depression with some success](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/17840/4397). Chronic pain is affected somewhat by a top-down process from the brain, as shown in [neurofeedback treatment via EEG](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23532434). Have hallucinogenics been shown to be an effective treatment for chronic pain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the National Institute for Drug Abuse](https://www.drugabuse.gov/publications/drugfacts/hallucinogens)

> Some hallucinogens interfere with the action of the brain chemical serotonin, which regulates:
>
> - mood
> - sensory perception
> - sleep
> - hunger
> - body temperature
> - sexual behavior
> - muscle control
>
> Other hallucinogens interfere with the action of the brain chemical glutamate, which regulates:
>
> - pain perception
> - responses to the environment
> - emotion
> - learning and memory

[Morphine is a hallucinogenic](https://doi.org/10.1186/1757-1626-2-9391) and

[Morphine is used to treat chronic pain](https://beta.nhs.uk/medicines/morphine/)

The NHS has also provided proof **with links to articles** that [opiates are useful for chronic pain](https://www.nhs.uk/news/medication/proof-opiates-are-useful-for-chronic-back-pain-lacking/)

Other hallucinogenics known to help with pain include [Peyote](http://hallucinogens.com/peyote/) (unreferenced)